# Check if `PreAuthorize` is present on method in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in my `Spring Boot` application. There i have configured the pipeline of security checks. There is also this:

```java
http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .anyRequest()
   .authenticated()
```

So every request is allowed as long as the requester is authenticated. Now I have added `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SOME_ROLE')")` to my methods. But if I miss one method, the default is allowed. How do I configure the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to permit all requests, to methods who not contain any `PreAuthorize` annotation?

I tried the `AccessDecisionManager`, but it does not work (or i am doing something wrong).

How do I configure it? It should be an easy thing, since permit should be default to secure the application.

Comment: I found this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access but it does not work with the http part.

Answer (score 1):

I have a current solution. Since all controllers implement one base controller, i just added `@PreAuthorize("denyAll()")` to the base controller.

Then if the implementation does not override `@PreAuthorize` with a custom value, every request will be denied. This is also written as best practice in the quarkus docs: https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-security

> Adding `@PreAuthorize("denyAll()")` to a method will ensure that that method is not accessible by any user. Adding it to a class will ensure that all public methods of the class that are not annotated with any other Spring Security annotation will not be accessible to any user.